# WP - Echo img if category is ... on the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to `echo` some specific images in the homepage **WordPress** loop. But I got some issues and it seems that WP is not recognizing the cat of my posts on the custom front page. I just want to build a if loop, and then if the category is ('videos'), I should display a specific image, etc.

Here is my loop :

```
<section class="home-actu">
                <div class="row">

        <?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=3');

        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        $the_query->the_post();

            ?>

            <article class="home-actu-article one-half column" style="background:url('<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?> <?php echo $url ?>');">
                <div class="home-actu-article-top">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
                    <div class="details-home-actu">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">THE IMAGE SHOULD BE HERE</a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">stuff here</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="home-actu-article-bottom-wrap">
                    <span class="home-actu-article-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt();?></span>
                    <span class="home-actu-article-bottom"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">En savoir <span>+</span></a></span>
                    <div class="social-home-actu">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>

        <?php  // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

                </div>
        </section>
```

I tried many things, but none of theme worked, and Im not familiar with the **WordPress** syntax / functions ...

Thanks everyone !

Comment: did you try `$catObj = get_the_category();`? you should get a PHP object of the current post's category. Now you didn't precise what to search in it, but usually testing the id should do (use `var_dump($catObj);` to display what's in the object if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this using the slug of the category and then a switch to change image for each post category:

```
<section class="home-actu">
                <div class="row">

        <?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=3');

        while ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        $the_query->the_post();

            ?>

            <article class="home-actu-article one-half column" style="background:url('<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?> <?php echo $url ?>');">
                <div class="home-actu-article-top">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
                    <div class="details-home-actu">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><?php

$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
$slug = $categories[0]->slug;
 switch($slug)
 {
  case "slugcat": 
    echo "<img src=\"....\">";  
  break;
  default:
  break;
 }
} 

?></a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">stuff here</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="home-actu-article-bottom-wrap">
                    <span class="home-actu-article-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt();?></span>
                    <span class="home-actu-article-bottom"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">En savoir <span>+</span></a></span>
                    <div class="social-home-actu">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>

        <?php  // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
        ?>

                </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx everyone, it work if you do :

```
<?php
   if ($catObj[0]->name == 'Actualités et évènements') {
       echo "<img src=\"PATH-TO-IMG\">";
      } elseif ($catObj[0]->name == 'Témoignages') {
       echo "<img src=\"PATH-TO-IMGs\">";
      } elseif ($catObj[0]->name == 'Vidéos'){
        echo "<img src=\"PATH-TO-IMG\" alt=\"Vidéos\">";
      } else {
        echo "";
      }
 ?>
```

Thx **Kaddath** for the var_dump and the get_category function, thx **Ciccio** for answering ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_category('videos',$post->ID)){
//show image
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/#parameters